# How to dynamically add columns to TableView and update their content

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following TableView:
[image]

Each row represents an Ingredient which have two properties, a name and a ArrayList of type Nutrient with the nutrients (name and weight) that composes the ingredient.

My goal is to **update the weight property of each Nutrient in the Array List of each Ingredient** by clicking on the corresponding cell and entering the new value (same behavior as the [Name column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMBd.png)).

I suspect that I need to set for each column a custom CellValueFactory and a CellFactory, but I'm new to JavaFx and I don't know exactly ho do do it.

This is the **Controller class** where most of the magic (should) happen:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TableView<Ingredient> tableView;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Ingredient, String> nameColumn;

    private final ObservableList<Ingredient> ingredientsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ArrayList<Nutrient> nutrientsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        
        // add ingredients and nutrients
        ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 1"));
        ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 2"));
        ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 3"));
        nutrientsList.add(new Nutrient("proteins", 0.0));
        nutrientsList.add(new Nutrient("fats", 0.0));
        nutrientsList.add(new Nutrient("carbs", 0.0));

        // add the list of nutrients to each ingredient
        ingredientsList.forEach(nutrient -> nutrient.setNutrients(nutrientsList));

        ingredientsList.forEach(System.out::println);

        //add ingredients (rows) to the table
        tableView.setItems(ingredientsList);

        // make name column editable
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Ingredient, String>("name"));

        for (int i = 0; i < nutrientsList.size(); i++) {
            // add a column for each ingredient
            TableColumn<Ingredient, Nutrient> column = new TableColumn<>(nutrientsList.get(i).getName());
            tableView.getColumns().add(column);

            Ingredient selectedIngredient = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            int currentNutrientIndex = i;
            column.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Ingredient, Nutrient>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Ingredient, Nutrient> ingredientNutrientCellEditEvent) {
                    selectedIngredient.updateNutrientValue(currentNutrientIndex, ingredientNutrientCellEditEvent.getNewValue().getWeight());
                }
            });

            // column.setCellFactory and column.setCellValueFactory here???
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method allows the user to double click on an cell and update the ingredient name.
     * It is linked to the UI by setting the attribute onEditCommit of the Column the the name of the method in the fxml file
     */
    public void changeIngredientNameCellEvent(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editedCell){
        Ingredient selectedIngredient = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        selectedIngredient.setName(editedCell.getNewValue().toString());
        ingredientsList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>

<TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" onEditCommit="#changeIngredientNameCellEvent" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

**Ingredient class:**

```
package sample;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ingredient {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private ArrayList<Nutrient> nutrients;

    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public void setNutrients(ArrayList<Nutrient> list){
        this.nutrients = list;
    }

    public void updateNutrientValue(int nutrientIndex, double newValue){
        nutrients.get(nutrientIndex).setWeight(newValue);
    }

    public Nutrient getNutrientAt(int index){
        return nutrients.get(index);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "name = '" + name.get() + "' nutrients = " + nutrients;
    }
}
```

**Nutrient class:**

```
package sample;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Nutrient {
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty weight;

    public Nutrient(String name, double weight) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.weight = new SimpleDoubleProperty(weight);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty weightProperty() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight.set(weight);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  name.get() + ", " + weight.get() ;
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nutrientsList.size(); i++) {
        // add a column for each ingredient
        TableColumn<Ingredient, Double> column = new TableColumn<>(nutrientsList.get(i).getName());
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);


        int currentNutrientIndex = i;
        

        // column.setCellFactory and column.setCellValueFactory here???

       column.setCellValueFactory(data -> 
           data.getValue().getNutrientAt(currentNutrientIndex).weightProperty().asObject());
       column.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    }
```

You may prefer to provide a custom `StringConverter` in place of the `DoubleStringConverter` to provide, e.g., localized parsing etc.

Note that the setup you have won't work correctly, but I assume this is just example code. You can't use the same list of `Nutrient`s for different ingredients (or indeed the same `Nutrient` instances, even in different lists). You need to create new instances for each `Ingredient`.

A fully working example can be made using

```
private final ObservableList<Ingredient> ingredientsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    
    // add ingredients and nutrients
    ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 1"));
    ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 2"));
    ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("ingredient 3"));
    
    List<String> nutrientNames = List.of("proteins", "fats", "carbs");
    
    // add a list of nutrients to each ingredient

    ingredientsList.forEach(ingredient -> ingredient.setNutrients(
        nutrientNames.stream()
            .map(name -> new Nutrient(name, 0.0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
    


    ingredientsList.forEach(System.out::println);

    //add ingredients (rows) to the table
    tableView.setItems(ingredientsList);

    // make name column editable
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
    

    for (int i = 0; i < nutrientNames.size(); i++) {
        // add a column for each ingredient
        TableColumn<Ingredient, Double> column = new TableColumn<>(nutrientNames.get(i));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);

        Ingredient selectedIngredient = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        int currentNutrientIndex = i;
        

        // column.setCellFactory and column.setCellValueFactory here???

       column.setCellValueFactory(data -> 
           data.getValue().getNutrientAt(currentNutrientIndex).weightProperty().asObject());
       column.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    }
}
```

with the additional change of changing the type of `Ingredient.nutrients` to `List<Nutrient>` (which is good practice anyway).